# How to convert postcode to Geolocation (latitude & longitude) using google maps api?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I just want to get latitude & longitude using the post code with Google maps API.

I am using PHP for development.

How can I do this?

The post code can be from any where in this world.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=address+geolocation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this using google map Geocoding API. Please find below example, but to correct latitude/longitude and address you need to pass full address along with zipcode.

For more detail please click on below link:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

```
<?php
$url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false";
$result = simplexml_load_file($url);
print"<pre>";
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: I needed a very specific thing, which I have no doubt is often looked up `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SW5+0RQ&sensor=false&components=country:UK`