# Google streets API

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

Have a few questions about this api:
1. Are we allowed to use this api from our api, not from website page?
2. We don't have Longitude and Latitude, but we have postcode of the houses, is it possible to get picture of the house by its postcode?

Our company is insurance company and we are allowed to do what I just asked, we just need to figure out the way to do it.

Comment: a) You should be asking one question per question, not two. b) For the postcode question, here's how: [How to convert postcode to Geolocation(latitude & longitutde) using google maps api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075912/how-to-convert-postcode-to-geolocationlatitude-longitutde-using-google-maps.)

Comment: You mean the StreetView Image API ? If so, yes you can use it from server-side

Answer (score 0):

On the second question you will struggle to get an image (via API alone) of the specific property from just the postcode in most countries as they typically cover more than one property.

Even with more of the address it can be hard for it to show the property, such as here, using "10 Tower Hill, Beccles NR34 9YN" the image is of garages rather the house at number 10, in fact the build to the right of the image is number 48.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x400&location=10%20tower%20hill%20beccles%20nr34%209yn

[image: Street View image of 10 Tower Hill, Beccles, UK]

I'm sure this will improve with time though.